# Trying to rename files of EchoBot to chatBot but getting error in deployment

Tags: azure, botframework

I created an echoBot and downloaded the code from Azure.I renamed the files from Echobot to ChatBot.It works fine in emulator,but when i try to deploy the code i get error:

```
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Zip deployment failed. 

{'id': '018e4353dacd4cd7aaf730e0c5233f85', 
'status': 3, 
'status_text': '', 
'author_email': 'N/A', 
'author': 'N/A', 
'deployer': 'Push-Deployer', 
'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 
'progress': '', 
'received_time': '2019-08-12T07:22:55.155264Z', 
'start_time': '2019-08-12T07:22:55.4365108Z', 
'end_time': '2019-08-12T07:22:59.3115417Z',
'last_success_end_time': None, 
'complete': True, 
'active': False, 
'is_temp': False, 
'is_readonly': True, 
'url': 'https://oasischat-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 
'log_url': 'https://oasischat-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 
'site_name': 'oasischat-dev', 
'provisioningState': None}.
 Please run the command az webapp log tail -n OasisChat-dev -g Oasischat


Log says:The logs says:
{"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"No log found for 'latest'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
"StackTrace":" at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentManager.cs:line 95\r\n at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\DeploymentController.cs:line 375"}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include your comment in the question itself?

Comment: how are you deploying?

Comment: Through Cli.Is there a way we can delete the files from server?

Comment: Off Azure? Yeah, you can gut your resource group, or delete the entire resource group easily through portal.azure.com